# Setting forecolor equal to backcolor in Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I need to hide text inside my cells (which contains formulas). I think of setting the text color same as background color (gray). Maybe a better alternative?

[image]

So I record a Macro for getting the code of setting the forecolor equal to backcolor (so gray). Then I stop the macro.

[image]

Now I reset the forecolor to `Automatic` (black) then running the recorded macro again to test. The result is that my forecolor is white which is strange because it should be gray.

[image]

Here is the code of the macro:

```
With rangeToHide.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
End With
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show the code of your macro? It's hard to guess what it is doing by just looking at the result.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add code.

Comment: Could you give a little more context to your code please? Variable declarations, where they are set, is your **With** within a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With rangeToHide
    .Font.Color = .Interior.Color
End With
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But this is `With rangeToHide` without `.Font`